# How to use command line options in a c command line tool?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how to use command line options with a command line c tool and I came accross this example.Can some one explain how the code flow works,I am not able to understand it,also I understand that it uses a getopt() function which is inbuilt.

The exe called is rocket_to and it has two command line options, e and a. e option takes 4 as an argument and a option takes Brasalia,Tokyo,London as argument.

Can some one explain how the code works?

This is the actual code:

command line:

```
rocket_to -e 4 -a Brasalia Tokyo London
```

code:

```
#include<unistd.h>
..
while((ch=getopt(argc,argv,"ae:"))!=EOF)
switch(ch){
..
case 'e':
 engine_count=optarg;
..
}
argc -=optind;
argv +=optind;
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell without more of the code.

Comment: The `-e` option takes an argument, and that is the `4` in the command line.  You can tell because of the `e:` in the third argument to `getopt()`.  The `-a` option takes no argument; you can tell because it is not followed by a colon in the third argument to `getopt()`.  The names `Brasilia`, `Tokyo`, `London` are non-option arguments after the option processing is complete.  They're the values in `argv[0]` .. `argv[argc-1]` after the two compound assignments outside the loop

Comment: -a doesn't take an argument; you can tell since there isn't a colon (:) after it in the call to getopt

Comment: Search for `getopt` or `getopt windows` and you will find a ton of links that explain everything.

Comment: Yeah, search before ask, there are already great answers out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many manual pages for [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) including the POSIX specification.  They describe what the `getopt()` function does.  You can also read the POSIX [Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) which describes how arguments are handled by most programs (but there are plenty of exceptions to the rules, usually because of historical, pre-POSIX precedent).

In the example outline code, the `-e` option takes an argument, and that is the `4` in the example command line.  You can tell because of the `e:` in the third argument to `getopt()` (the colon following the letter indicates that the option takes an argument).  The `-a` option takes no argument; you can tell because it is not followed by a colon in the third argument to `getopt()`.  The names `Brasilia`, `Tokyo`, `London` are non-option arguments after the option processing is complete.  They're the values in `argv[0]` .. `argv[argc-1]` after the two compound assignments outside the loop.

The use of `EOF` is incorrect; `getopt()` returns `-1` when there are no more options for it to process.  You don't have to include `<stdio.h>` to be able to use `getopt()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch;
    int aflag = 0;
    char *engine_count = "0";
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "ae:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'a':
            aflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'e':
            engine_count = optarg;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-a][-e engine] [name ...]\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    printf("A flag = %d\n", aflag);
    printf("Engine = %s\n", engine_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

That is working code which, if compiled to create a program `rocket_to`, produces:

```
$ ./rocket_to -e 4 -a Brasilia Tokyo London
A flag = 1
Engine = 4
argv[0] = Brasilia
argv[1] = Tokyo
argv[2] = London
$ ./rocket_to -a -e 4 Brasilia Tokyo London
A flag = 1
Engine = 4
argv[0] = Brasilia
argv[1] = Tokyo
argv[2] = London
$ ./rocket_to -e -a 4 Brasilia Tokyo London
A flag = 0
Engine = -a
argv[0] = 4
argv[1] = Brasilia
argv[2] = Tokyo
argv[3] = London
$
```

Comment: Thanks....cool...I think I get it now,but i still dont understand this line though:         argc-= optind;
    argv += optind; what does it do?? what does the variable optind store?

Comment: AFAIAC, it's not the way I write the code, but it is the way your sample code was written.  It adjusts the pointer `argv` (argument vector) so that it points to the first non-option argument, and it adjusts the argument count `argc` so that it contains the number of non-option arguments.  The global variable `optind` is managed by `getopt()` and tells you where the non-option arguments are.  I'd normally not adjust `argv` or `argc`; I'd use: `for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++) process(argv[i]);` instead.  That's mostly a matter of taste, though.

Answer (score 1):

From the getopt man page:

> The  getopt()  function  parses the command-line arguments.  Its arguments argc and argv are the argument count and array as passed to
>          the main() function on program invocation.  An element of argv that starts with '-' (and is not exactly "-" or "--") is an option element.   The  characters  of  this  element  (aside  from the initial '-') are option characters.  If getopt() is called repeatedly, it
>          returns successively each of the option characters from each of the option elements.

The 3rd argument to `getopt()` are the valid options. If the option is followed by a colon it requires an argument. The argument can be accessed through the optarg variable. So in your example you have two options: 'a'  which takes no argument and 'e' which takes an argument.

If `getopt()` finds an options it returns the character. If all options are parsed it returns -1 and if an unknown option is found it returns -1.

So your code loops through all options and processes them in a switch statement.

Next time when you have trouble understanding something like this try to run `man <unknown function>` first.